# OR Not query in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a query that works in mysql

```
SELECT events.id 
FROM events LEFT JOIN events_cstm ON events.id = events_cstm.id_c 
WHERE event_date_time_c >= NOW() OR NOT {0}'
```

It does not work in MSSQL I need the equivalent query that will do exactly the same thing.

So far I have:

```
SELECT events.id 
FROM events LEFT JOIN events_cstm ON events.id = events_cstm.id_c 
WHERE event_date_time_c >= getutcdate() OR NOT {0}'
```

But I keep getting about error inappropriate boolean or something. The {0} is a value of a checkbox that’s put in by the application. Could be 1 or 0.

Comment: Which application are you talking about?  This app supports MySQL and MSSQL?

Comment: SugarCRM it does support both

Comment: Did you try `OR {0} = 0`?

Comment: I dont think that will work. The query is subquery of a larger query. I really need to know if there is an OR NOT equivalent in MSSQL?

Comment: Well, if you want to use `OR NOT` then it's `OR NOT {0} = 1` but that's difficult to read.

Comment: Can you specify the column name of the Checkbox and remove the {}? OR NOT Checkbox = 0

Comment: 1 = {0} seems to do the trick as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
1 = {0}
```

or whatelse could be the valid clause (eg 0 = {0})